# Can I let user to multi select some titles in Application Preferences?

Tags: iphone, preferences

I know I can use PSMultiValueSpecifier to let user to choose a value from a list.

But it is a single select.

How can I let user to be able to multi choose some values, in Application Preferences?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no.

i believe you need to create multiple boolean values to track each of the item. Similar to the settings for Location Services